# How to add parameter to a family in Revit using Revit API in C#?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to add a parameter to a Revit family. When I open the Revit Family document and execute the code below in a macro, I get this error:

> System.Exception: Document regeneration failed. at
> MacroModule.executeMacro_(MacroModule*, AString* MacroName) at
> MacroModule.executeMacro_(MacroModule*, AString* ) at
> UIMacroGeneralManager.runMacro(UIMacroGeneralManager*, MacroModule*
> pModule, AString* macroName)

Any idea how to solve this issue?

```
public void FamilyInstanceParameters()
{
    Document document = this.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView.Document;
    if (!document.IsFamilyDocument)
    {
        TaskDialog.Show("Info", "This is not a FamilyDocument");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(document);
            transaction.Start("Param");

            // Get the family document category
            Family family = document.OwnerFamily;
            Category category = family.FamilyCategory;

            FamilyType familyType = document.FamilyManager.NewType("New Type A");
            document.FamilyManager.CurrentType = familyType;


            // Parameter group
            BuiltInParameterGroup builtInParamGroup = BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_IDENTITY_DATA;


            document.Regenerate();
            FamilyParameter familyParameter = document.FamilyManager
               .AddParameter("parameterName", builtInParamGroup, category, false);

            document.FamilyManager.Set(familyParameter, "parameterValue");

            transaction.Commit();
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your code in the debugger and determine exactly which line is causing the problem. If it is the call to `document.Regenerate`, maybe it can simply be skipped. For numerous detailed solutions, please search the [Revit API discussion forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api/bd-p/160) for [add family parameter](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&filter=location&location=forum-board:160&q=add%20family%20parameter).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The error occurs at "FamilyParameter familyParameter = document.FamilyManager
               .AddParameter("parameterName", builtInParamGroup, category, false);". I suspect that something other than the code might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using the below method overload:

> public FamilyParameter AddParameter(  string parameterName,
> ForgeTypeId groupTypeId,    ForgeTypeId specTypeId,     bool isInstance )

```
public void FamilyInstanceParameters()
{
    Document document = this.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView.Document;
    if (!document.IsFamilyDocument)
    {
        TaskDialog.Show("Info", "This is not a FamilyDocument");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(document);
            transaction.Start("Param");

            // Get the family document category
            Family family = document.OwnerFamily;
            Category category = family.FamilyCategory;

            FamilyType familyType = document.FamilyManager.NewType("New Type A");
            document.FamilyManager.CurrentType = familyType;


            // ParameterName en value
            string parameterName = "parameterNameLength";
            int parameterValue = 20;

            FamilyParameter familyParameter = document.FamilyManager.AddParameter(parameterName: parameterName, groupTypeId: GroupTypeId.Constraints, specTypeId: SpecTypeId.Length, isInstance: false);


            document.FamilyManager.Set(familyParameter, parameterValue);

            transaction.Commit();
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to add text parameter

```
    public void AddParameter(Document familyDoc)
    {
        using(Transaction tx = new Transaction(familyDoc, "AddParameter"))
        {
            tx.Start();
            
            familyDoc.FamilyManager.NewType("New Type A"); //add new type - "new type" becomes current type
            FamilyParameter familyParameter = familyDoc.FamilyManager.AddParameter("parameterName", GroupTypeId.IdentityData, SpecTypeId.String.Text, false); //method overload to add text parameter
            familyDoc.FamilyManager.Set(familyParameter, "parameterValue");
            //familyDoc.FamilyManager.SetFormula(familyParameter, "\"parameterValue\"");
            
            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
```